# Zend framework controller action helper

Tags: php, zend-controller

I am getting fatal error after adding the action helper class. I am trying to load layout corresponding to called layout. Following is my code snippet:

First of all i added a helper class under application/controller/helpers:

```
class Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Layout extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {

public $pluginLoader;


public function __construct() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated Constructor
    $this->pluginLoader = new Zend_Loader_PluginLoader ();
}


public function preDispatch()
{
        $bootstrap = $this->getActionController()->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
        $config = $bootstrap->getOptions();
        $module = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
        if (isset($config[$module]['resources']['layout']['layout'])) {
            $layoutScript = $config[$module]['resources']['layout']['layout'];
            $this->getActionController()->getHelper('layout')->setLayout($layoutScript);
        }

    }

}
```

**Then i added a loader in bootstrap.php:**

```
protected function _initLayoutHelper() {

    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH .'/controllers/helpers');

    $layout = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Layout());
}
```

**Following is my application.ini:**

```
[production]
autoloaderNamespaces.tree = "Tree_"
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.helperDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers/helpers"

resources.modules[] = ""
contact.resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "index"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = layout
admin.resources.layout.layout = admin
#admin.resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"

resources.view[] =

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

**While running this code i am getting following errors:**

> Warning:
>   include(Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\LayoutLoader.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\personal\proj\renovate\library\Zend\Loader.php
>   on line 83
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]:
>   Failed opening
>   'Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\LayoutLoader.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='D:\personal\proj\renovate\application/../library;D:\personal\proj\renovate\library;.;C:\php5\pear')
>   in
>   D:\personal\proj\renovate\library\Zend\Loader.php
>   on line 83
>
> Fatal error: Class
>   'Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_LayoutLoader'
>   not found in
>   D:\personal\proj\renovate\application\Bootstrap.php
>   on line 33

Kindly let me know, how can i come out from this issue. I am beginner in Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have invalid `include_path`

Try insert this in the index.php:

```
define('ROOTDIR', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('LIBDIR', realpath(ROOTDIR . '../library') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array_merge(explode(PATH_SEPARATOR,ini_get('include_path')), array(LIBDIR))));
```

This works for directory structure like:

```
application/
library/
- Zend/
httpdocs/
- index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I think include path is valid. Following is my index.php

Define path to application directory

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH') || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

Define application environment

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));
```

Ensure `library/` is on `include_path`

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),get_include_path(),)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php'; 

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
$application->bootstrap()->run();
```